# Get alias of model association alias in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I'm using CakePHP 2.6.3.

I have multiple associations to the same model and I'd like to apply some slightly different beforeValidate() logic depending on which association it is. I thought that in the model `$this->alias` would update with the alias name of the association, but it only seems to be the class name.

Using the [Multiple Relations to Same Model](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#multiple-relations-to-the-same-model) example in the cookbook, how could I tell whether the Sender (User model) or the Recipient (User model) is being validated?

```
function beforeValidate($options = array()) {
    if ($association == 'Sender') {
        // do something
    } else {
        // do something different
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $alias property is only used with a different name than the original model name when the model is used through an association. The alias should be always used in the model itself. For example `$this->Blog->Author` the alias for the user model would he "Author" here, assuming this:

```
$belongsTo = ['Author' => ['className' => 'User']];
```

So either save you data through one side of the validation or simply pass an identifier along with your data.

```
if ($this->data[$this->alias]['is_sender'] == true) { /*...*/ } else { /*...*/ }
```

In your beforeValidate().

If its not the  sender it's the receiver.

Comment: Thanks. I was using `saveAll()` so the alias wasn't being used. I like the idea of the identifier, as it keeps me from having to validate each model individually.